# I am extremely new to programming, i am trying to write this program in C and after compiling I keep getting an error message

Tags: c

I am extremely new to coding. I am working on this program for class, and after reading the textbook, I am still a little lost. I really had to search around in google to get help with this program. After compiling, I keep getting

`[Error} expected unqualified-id before '{' token".`

This is my code:

```
    /* This program is intended to compute the following: 

    1) Prompt for the input of one edge of a cube
    2) Calculate the area for one side of the cube
    3) Calculate the surface area of the cube
    4) calculate the volume of the cube
    5) Display all input and calculated values 
    */

    #include<stdio.h>

    //Below is the program code for the surface area of a cube

    int main() {
    float side, surfaceArea;
    printf("Enter length of any side of cube\n");

    scanf("%f", &side);
    surfaceArea = 6*side*side;
    printf("Total surface area of Cube : %0.4f\n",
        surfaceArea);

    return 0;

    }

    //Below is the C program to calculate the volume of a cube

     #include <stdio.h> 


     {

        float side, volume;
        printf("Enter length of any side of cube\n");
        scanf("%f", &side);
        volume = side*side*side;
        printf("Volume of Cube : %0.4f\n", volume);

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Your second program (for volume of cube) is missing the `main` function.

Comment: You see, you have mistakenly 'combined' two programs into one. After your comment "Below is a C program to calculate the volume of a cub" you have an `include` and you probably removed main from there to get rid of an error. Technically that is all a separate program, remove it and place it in another file.

Comment: Place both codes in separate files or make appropraite functions to keep both functionality in the same file.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I was gonna ask next, if i should save all of these in separate files.

Comment: One `main` function per project. All executable code statements must be within a function (with the exception of initialising global variables as part of their definition).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 different programs i can see above.
First program is correct, save it in on file say "surfaceArea.c". Second program does not contain main() function. So after #include write the line int main()
save this program as volume.c